# If $\tan^2(\theta)+2\sec^2(\theta)=5$. Find the value of $\sin^2(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a trig problem which i can't really understand where to start. It says

If $$\tan^2(θ)+2\sec^2(θ)=5.$$ Find the value of $$\sin^2(θ).$$

I think it has something with to do with Pythagorean theorem. Maybe you guys can give me a head start to where should I start.

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: i got $$sin^2θ=\frac{1}{2}$$. is it correct

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Since $\color{blue}{\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}}$ and $\color{blue}{\sec \theta=\frac{1}{\cos \theta}}$ we have, by multiplying by $\cos^2\theta$:
\begin{align}
\sin^2\theta+2&=5\cos^2\theta\\
\sin^2\theta+2&=5(1-\sin^2\theta)\qquad \text{since }\;\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1\\
\end{align}

Comment: i got $$sin^2θ=\frac{1}{2}$$. is it correct

Comment: @user306498 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

Note that by dividing both sides of the trigonometric Pythagorean Identity by $\cos^2\theta$, we get

$$\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta$$

so we need

$$\tan^2\theta + 2\tan^2\theta + 2 = 5$$
$$3\tan^2\theta = 3$$
$$\tan^2\theta = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^2\theta+2\sec^2\theta=5=5(\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta)$$

$$\iff\tan^2\theta(1+5)=\sec^2\theta(5-2)$$

Now $\sin^2\theta=\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}=?$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \ , \ \ \sec \theta=\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan^2\theta+2\sec^2\theta=\tan^2\theta+2(\tan^2\theta+1)=3\tan^2\theta+2=5\implies\tan\theta=\pm1$$
Now, draw a diagram